# What does the dot in the English transcription of the word "eerie" mean?

Tags: transcription

Here is the transcription /ˈɪr.i/. It is from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/eerie). Does it mean that I need to say the letter *r* and *i* separately? If so, then I am confused because I thought that it is the role of the apostrophy to separate sounds like in the word *interact*. It is clear that we read this word as two separate words *inter* and *act*. Here is the transcription ​ /ˌɪn.t̬ɚˈækt/.

Answer (score 3):

The dot denotes where a word is broken into syllables

1. UK ee•rie **/ˈɪə.ri/**
   US eer•ie; **/ˈɪr.i/**  (two syllables)
2. beau•ti•ful; **[/bjuː.tɪ.f <sup>ə</sup> l/](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/beautiful)** (three syllables)

Comment: The dot should be on the line, but there is variation in actual use.

Comment: I placed the dot midway for the sake of clarity, and some references also position the dot that way.

Answer (score 2):

In a phonetic transcription, the apostrophe (actually a short straight down mark placed between letters above the line) indicates the primary stress, and a similar mark placed on the line indicates secondary stress. A dot placed on the line indicates a syllable break. See the section on "suprasegmentals" in an [IPA chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8e/IPA_chart_2018.pdf)

In General American pronunciation the word is /ˈɪr.i/ with a syllable break after the /r/

British pronunciation is /ˈɪə.ri/